# Django | Does not filter questions using categories

Tags: django

Web that does not filter questions using categories.
Where is the error?
Thanks!

**template**

```
 {% for categoria in categorias %}
       <a href="{{ url 'preguntas'}}/{{ categoria.id }}"><p>{{ categoria.categoriaEUS }}</p></a>
    {% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Pregunta(models.Model):
    categoria = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria, null=True, blank=True)
    textoES = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    textoEUS = models.ManyToManyField(Euskara, null=True, blank=True)


class Categoria(models.Model):
    categoriaES = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    categoriaEUS = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
 def pregunta_list(request,categoria_id):
        preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(categoria='categoria_id').order_by('id')
        paginator = Paginator(preguntas,1)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        preguntas = paginator.get_page(page)
        return render(request, 'pregunta/pregunta.html', {'preguntas': preguntas})

    def categoria_list(request):
        categorias = Categoria.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'pregunta/categoria.html', {'categorias': categorias})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('',
    views.pregunta_list,
    name='preguntas/<int:pk>/',
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not put the parameter and the name, since the path that is constructed will not contain that parameter. If later the user visits the link, then the parameter does not exists.

You thus should create a path with:

```
path(
    'preguntas/<int:categoria_id>/',
    views.pregunta_list,
    name='pregunta_list'
),
```

and in the template, you can then render the url with:

```
{% for categoria in categorias %}
       <a href="{% url 'pregunta_list' categoria_id=categoria.id %}"><p>{{ categoria.categoriaEUS }}</p></a>
{% endfor %}
```

You also used a string literal instead of an identifier in the view:

```
def pregunta_list(request, categoria_id):
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(categoria=categoria_id).order_by('id')
    paginator = Paginator(preguntas,1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    preguntas = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'pregunta/pregunta.html', {'preguntas': preguntas})
```

Comment: Thanks. But it says: ValueError at /gaiak/preguntas/1/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'categoria_id'

Comment: Thanks again Willem Van Onsem ; ) but it show: NoReverseMatch at /gaiak/gaiak/
Reverse for 'preguntas' not found. 'preguntas' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @julian: ah yes, that should have been `pregunta_list`.

Comment: Thanks for all, Willem Van Onsem. I´m new with Django. I love it. ; )